# SonarLint.xml and Codacy Sonar Sharp configuration

Tags: xml, github, docker-compose, containers, static-code-analysis

I am using this docker image to analyze my code: codacy/codacy-sonar-csharp
https://github.com/codacy/codacy-sonar-csharp

It works great. But I have some issues with the SonarLint.xml configuration and can't find any specific documentation or information regarding it.

I am using something like this

```
codacy:
  image: codacy/codacy-sonar-csharp
  volumes:
    - ./:/src/MyProject/
    - ./SonarLint.xml:/src/SonarLint.xml
```

I don't even need to execute any specific command. It will analyze anything what will be in /src folder. Thus, it is passing this SonarLint.xml to it.
But now it starts to become really curious.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnalysisInput>
    <Rules>
        <Rule>
            <Key>S3904</Key>
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter>
                    <Key>enabled</Key>
                    <Value>false</Value>
                </Parameter>
            </Parameters>
        </Rule>
    </Rules>
</AnalysisInput>
```

I want to turn off the S3904, right ?
Well.. now it will output ONLY S3904!
And I can't understand why!

If I won't move this SonarLint.xml configuration file and start my code analysis without any configuration. It will output all errors and warning.

If I will follow the example described in GitHub.
And my configuration file would be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnalysisInput>
  <Rules>
    <Rule>
      <Key>S103</Key>
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter>
          <Key>maximumLineLength</Key>  
          <Value>24</Value>  
        </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
    </Rule>
  </Rules>
</AnalysisInput>
```

The output will be the same as with S3904. It will output only S103 messages now.

```
{"filename":"Program.cs","message":"Split this 46 characters long line (which is greater than 24 authorized).","patternId":"S103","line":8}
```

This isn't right at all.. I want exactly the opposite!
But where is the documentation regarding all of this ?

Programming should help people and reduce all of the unnecessary work.
While here.. I can't even imagine how much time it will take me to map ALL the errors! It's insane

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Yeah.. I just made an automatic generator xml configuration program inside my program. 
And I'm passing those arguments that I don't want to be displayed to it. 

It wasn't that hard